# split values in arraylist and store in different array list

Tags: java, android

I am doing a project in android ,and i have a problem My array list values like this

[name1, addr1, place1, name2, addr2, place2]

How can i split this values and want to store name, address, places in different array list?

Comment: Your array will always be in thies format.? [name1, addr1, -place1, name2, addr2, -place2]. i.e first name then addres then place

Comment: [name1, addr1, place1, name2, addr2, place2]

Comment: anoop from where you get this array list ...i mean from webservice?

Comment: @anoop And how is the current array list different from the desired one?

Comment: @Samir Mangroliya : yes Its from web service..

Comment: @user1288160 : My array list contain 3 different type values...
I want to split this and put in 3 different arraylist

Comment: @anoop I don't know if I understood you correctly, but I posted my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<String> allInfo, names, addresses, places;
//init everythin
for(int i=0; i<allInfo.size();i++)
  switch( i % 3 ){
     case 0:
        names.add(allInfo.get(i));
        break;
     case 1:
        addresses.add(allInfo.get(i));
        break;
     case 2:
        places.add(allInfo.get(i));
        break;
  }
```

Or the more efficient aproach

```
for(Iterator itr=allInfo.iterator(), int i=0; itr.hasNext(); i++)
    switch( i % 3 ){
         case 0:
            names.add(itr.next());
            break;
         case 1:
            addresses.add(itr.next());
            break;
         case 2:
            places.add(itr.next());
            break;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split your array into different array in the following way.

```
    ArrayList<String> mainArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    //mainArray Has Data now we want to shift it into different arrays
    ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> address = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> place = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0;i<mainArray.size();i++){
        switch(i%3){
        case 0:
            name.add(mainArray.get(i));
            break;
        case 1:
            address.add(mainArray.get(i));
            break;
        case 2:
            address.add(mainArray.get(i));
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> yourArrayList; //this is you array list which have names, addresses and places in it

ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> addresses = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> places = new ArrayList<String>();

for(int i =0;i<yourArrayList.length;i++){ //iterate yourArrayList and for every element, add it in a seperate array list 
    if(i%3==0)
        names.add(yourArrayList[i])

    else if(i%3==1)
        addresses.add(yourArrayList[i]);

    else if(i%3==2)
        places.add(arraylist[i]);
}
```